# What happens when a Mage Hand takes damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, damage

If a Mage Hand triggers a trap (in my case, by screwing a lightbulb into a booby-trapped socket) or otherwise takes damage from some effect, what happens to it? Does it just sit there and ignore the damage? Does it go "poof"?  Does the caster have to make a Concentration check to keep the spell going?  Does the caster take the damage in lieu of the Mage Hand? Does either the Mage Hand or the character have to roll a saving throw?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mage hand doesn't make a hand, therefore there is nothing to effect.  Reread [the spell description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mageHand.htm). It's just telekinesis on one object.  If your game plays that there's a "special effect" of a hand that appears, that's fine, but has no bearing on the spell effect, which has no such thing.

Answer (score 11):

Since "mage hand" isn't described as a construct of any sort or having any hit points, I'd assume nothing happens. Heck, part of the appeal of Mage Hand is that it nets you fine manipulation at range with little risk to yourself.